DNS not working after switching to VPN and back? (Home network)
I have a raspberry pi, hostname raspberrypi, on my home network that I can usually connect to just fine - I didn't have to set anything up, it just worked after it was plugged in, presumably using my home router as a DNS server.
However, if I turn my VPN (Nord VPN, if it makes any difference) on for a bit and then off again to be able to use my local network, I don't seem to be able to use the raspberrypi hostname to connect any more. I can still access it by IP address, so I can definitely see it, and other devices can still access by hostname, so the DNS seems to still be working.
So it seems that the machine that used the VPN is no longer able to lookup the hostname, for some reason... any idea how I go about diagnosing/fixing this?
